# BASEX - Getting unique values from within a variable

Tags: xpath, xquery, basex

I'm trying to create a list of all the different prefixes to titles used in a database. The titles are stored in an xml tag as content text(as opposed to an attribute).

Having extracted all of the titles, I want to create a list of unique prefixes ( the titles themselves are descriptors, not unique identifiers).

I've gotten to the point of having the prefix from every title. What I want to do now is to remove the doubles to leave just a short list of unique values.

I've tried using distinct-values() but it seems to me that this is operating on the original title(i.e. the content of the tags) and not on the variable I created.

I've also tried converting into and out of and array, but that doesn't yield the result I want either.

```
for $name in db:open('DUMMYDATABASE')//body
let $new := $name/mytitle
let $thetitles :=  array { tokenize(replace($new, 's', ''), '-')[1] }
let $result := <thing>{distinct-values($names)}</thing>

return $result
```

What I'm trying to do is go from something like this:

```
<tag>con.text1</tag>
<tag>sub.text1</tag>
<tag>con.text2</tag>
<tag>sub.text2</tag>
<tag>para.text</tag>
<tag>super.text</tag>
```

to something iterable like this
"con", "sub", "para", "super"

so that I will later be able to iterate over that sequence to find documents.

Comment: If  `$new` is a sequence of `mytitle` elements with values like `con.text1` then you can use `distinct-values($new/substring-before(., '.'))` to get a sequence of strings with unique prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you pretty far:

```
distinct-values(//body/tag/tokenize(., '\.')[1])
```

When applied to

```
<body>
  <tag>con.text1</tag>
  <tag>sub.text1</tag>
  <tag>con.text2</tag>
  <tag>sub.text2</tag>
  <tag>para.text</tag>
  <tag>super.text</tag>
</body>
```

it results in four values: `'con', 'sub', 'para', 'super'`.